# Git log up to a certain commit

Tags: git

I know it's possible to use `git log` to get commit history between two commits, between two dates, since a date, before a date, and so on..but I've yet to see a way to get a log up to a certain commit.

I know this probably doesn't exist because of the problem of having multiple commits with the same parent/no parent (hard to find the definitive first commit), but is there a workaround?

I've been doing this...

Get the first commit:
`FIRST_COMMIT=git rev-list HEAD | tail -n 1`

Get between first and commit I want
`git log FIRST_COMMIT..ff353d1`

But is there a better way? Like using from the beginning of time up unto the time of the commit I want to use?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. If you ask for ```git log revision''', You will get all revisions on the history of that revision (which is more or less what I think you achieve with the commands you just showed).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`git log FIRST_COMMIT..ff353d1` shows (mostly) the same as `git log ff353d1`, you don't need to be too fancy. If you want it in reverse order - just use `git log --reverse ff353d1`.

Answer (score -1):

Consider a history where A is a more recent commit than B. If I want a log from A to B inclusive, `git log <commit A>...<commit B>~1` does the trick (on git version 2.21.0).